# Determining time complexity for the following coded segment

Tags: python, time-complexity

How do I determine the time complexity of this coded segment? I'm new to python and would really appreciate any kind of help!

```
sum = 0
i = n
while (i>= 1):
    sum += i
    i /= 2
i = n
j = 2
while (i >= 1):
    sum +=i
    i /= j
    j *= 2
```

I thought the first loop might be (log n + 2) and the second loop might be (2log n + 4) but I'm not sure if I'm even close to being on the right track...

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you think that? If not, we can obviously only guess whether you're on the right track.

Comment: What does this have to do with `canopy`?

Comment: As this is obviously homework, please explain your rationale for coming to the conclusions you've reached.

Comment: Also, this is two separate questions in one. Ask the first question, get an answer, then either that will be all you needed, or you can post a new question for the second one.

Comment: As a side note, you don't need—and shouldn't use—parens around `while` conditions. And it's a bad idea to name a variable `sum`, because that shadows the built-in function of the same name (which you might want to use to, e.g., check the results of your loop).

Comment: Another note: constants are not relevant in time complexity analysis. So if you write (log n + 2) or (log n + c) for any possible c, it's equivalent. This because the greater n gets the lesser c modifies the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my answer. To be more mathematically-precise you probably should write inequations instead of equation as I did, but anyway the overall reasoning would not change.
Let me know by comments if it makes sense or you find errors.

### First Loop

The first loop is iterated as many time as it would take to get i down to lesser than 1.

Its time complexity is `O(log_2(n+1))` where by log_2 I mean logarithm based on 2.

```
0  i = n
1  i = n / 2
2  i = n / 2 / 2
k  i = n/ 2^k
```

You ask yourself: what is k such that `n = 2^k` ?

```
k = log_2(n)
```

Of course, you don't get distracted by var sum as the variable does not interfere with the one driving the loop.

### Second Loop

The second loop is also driven by the division of i by a multiple of 2 but that is speed up at each iteration by multiplying `j * 2`. Its time complexity is log_2(n+1)/2.

```
1  i = n / 2                           j = 2
2  i = n / 2 / 2 / 2                   j = 4
3  i = n / 2 / 2 / 2 / 2 / 2 / 2       j = 8
k  i = n / 2^(k) * 2^(k)               j = 2^k
k  i = n / 2^(2k)                      j = 2^k
```

At each iteration `k, j = 2^k`.

At iteration `k+1`, `j = 2^(k+1)`.

So iteration `k+1`: `i /= 2^(k+1)`

What is k such that `n = 2^(2k)` ?

```
2k = log_2(n)
k = log_2(n)/2
log_2(n)/2
log_2(sqrt(n))
```

### Code segment

The two loops are not nested and i is reset to n between them, so they just sum up.

```
log_2(n+1) + log_2(sqrt(n+1))
log_2(n+1 + sqrt(n+1))
```

Comment: Should log calculus be unclear you can check [here](https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m116/logs/properties.html)

Comment: Note that log(sqrt n) = 1/2 log n = O(log n).

Comment: That's true. However I did not write the big-O notation as neither the OP did. So it's more counting the steps than asymptotic analysis.. I was waiting for a feedback to edit if needed.

Comment: @templatetypedef do you anyway confirm my analysis? It's been a while that I haven't done any.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of Computational Complexity, O(n) refers the actual bit length (they call n the bit length).

So, each time **i** runs through the first loop, the **i /= 2** shifts one bit. In the second loop, **i /= j** shifts 1, 2, 4, 8... bits.

Remember you have a variable named **n**, while the *n* (input's bit length) I talked about is, actually, a convention regarding CC theory.

So, assume you have the script you wrote with just a variable rename: **n** to **m**.

```
sum = 0

i = m
while (i>= 1):
    sum += i
    i /= 2

i = m
j = 2
while (i >= 1):
    sum +=i
    i /= j
    j *= 2
```

I just renamed the variable.

Now let's sum:

The first loop has a "bit-by-bit" complexity, so the notation is O(n) (linear complexity, one bit per iteration).

**Edit**: The **second** loop has a complexity as follows: "in the Kth loop, it will consume 1+2+...+2^(k-1) bits: it will consume 2^K - 1 bits".

So if the Kth loop consumes that amount of bits, we say: K iterations for 2^K bits. We say "logarithmic": O(log2(n)).

The final result is: O(log2(n)) + O(n), which has a linear order, since n > log(n).

Comment: Wait a moment.. the complexity of the first loop is linear to the number of the input's bit **not** the input number in general. Right? Because you're thinking in binary notation..

Comment: Yes. O(n) is not about the input number, but about the input's bit length. AND n is log2(m) rounded up.

Comment: Another comment: it's important to understand that CC is about bit lengths since many cryptography related problems square their resolution time (their complexity) when the bit lengths used for the keys are doubled.

Comment: Ok, so our answers agree :) but I haven't renamed n=log2(m) and after all I actually counted the steps because I wasn't sure what he wanted. Nice trick the bitwise ;)

Comment: :). No, i renamed the variable so i could explain CC using the notation and not confuse you while quoting your code.

Comment: You are getting confused: it's not my code you're quoting. And my __answer__ IS equivalent to yours.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47710/discussion-between-niccolo-and-luis-masuelli)